# Probability of lines intersecting in a square.

Tags: probability, geometry

Suppose that you select two random line segments in a square, by selecting their endpoints uniformly at random. What is the probability that they intersect?

Comment: Does the point of intersection have to lie strictly inside the square?

Comment: Yes. They do have to be

Comment: So quite an elementary problem, requiring a good number of non-trivial steps.

Comment: If the four selected points are the vertices of a convex quadrilateral, the conditional probability is $\frac{1}{3}$. If the convex envelope is a triangle, the conditional probability is $0$, hence the problem boils down to computing the probability that the convex envelope of such four random points is a triangle.

Comment: Given the first three random points, the probability that the fourth point lies inside the previous triangle just depends on the area of such triangle. So the problem boils down to computing the distribution of the area of a triangle defined by three random points in a square. That can be done through the shoelace formula and a multiple integral.

Comment: Or through symmetry arguments. For instance, it is known that the average area of a random triangle in a unit square is $\frac{11}{144}$, see http://people.missouristate.edu/lesreid/AdvSol41.html